# How to filter contiguous elements with stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I wonder if there's a way to filter contiguous/interconnected elements with java's stream API?

To give you the background of this problem: I retrieve a list of traffic lines which contain different stops. As a user I now only want to know the travel time and stations which are on my route from X to Y.
So I somehow need to filter all the sections (stop a -> stop b) which are interconnected.

I've got a list of **unsorted** Objects which cointain the fields **start** and **end**. I now want to retrieve a list which only cointains the elements which are logically connected between those two points.
Here a simple example:

I want to filter for **start B** and **end E**

```
List to filter: {A,B},{B,C},{C,D},{D,E},{E,F}
List I want:    {B,C},{C,D},{D,E}
```

Comment: How about dropWhile(thing::doesnotstartwithb) and then takeUntil(thing::endswithe)

Comment: The Idea isn't bad but then again the list is not really ordered. Which means necessary elements could occur before that point.

Comment: I see. Are you using your own data structure, with nodes connecting to each other like in a linked list or tree?

Comment: Please add the that list isn't sorted to your Question. Also, is it possible that the list looks like this `{Q,A}{A,B},{B,C},{C,D},{D,E},{E,F}{F,G}` so that you want to drop two items in both ends? Or will it ever only have to drop one item in each end?

Comment: @Scratte Yes, exactly. In this case I would want to drop {Q,A},{A,B},{E,F} and {F,G}

Comment: Then I think the answer is: No :) To use the Streams API you need to be able to evaluate each element separately, or rather the handling of elements needs to be stateless. This is not the case with your list. Even if your elements are sorted, there's a different criteria for your pre-start than your after-end filter. In addition, you cannot sort the elements using a regular `Comparator`, since the comparison of `{D,E}` and `{Q,A}` should probably be undefined or null. Please add the new information into your Question too :)

Comment: why are you using a list when you clearly need a `Graph` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the Streams API isn't meant for stateful operations. A comparison using a `Comparator` isn't feasible since the comparison of `{D,E}` and `{Q,A}` should probably be undefined or null. That rules out the [`sorted​(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)) method. I also don't think doing a complex sorting of the elements into a `LinkedList` makes sense either.

I think a much simpler solution would be to just put your elements into a map. And fetch the next element based on that.

Your notation

> List to filter: {A,B},{B,C},{C,D},{D,E},{E,F}

looks a little like a a list of arrays, so that's what I went with.

Once the arrays are mapped to their keys, which is just the first element of the array, you can follow the path of fetching the next array based on the key:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StackOverflowTest3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // The full route starts in Vilnius and ends in Seattle
    List<String[]> unsortedList
        = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new String[]{"Copenhagen","Amsterdam"},
                                  new String[]{"Vilnius","Riga"},
                                  new String[]{"Rotterdam","New York"},
                                  new String[]{"Chicago","Seattle"},
                                  new String[]{"Amsterdam","Rotterdam"},
                                  new String[]{"New York","Chicago"},
                                  new String[]{"Riga","Copenhagen"}));

    // Put the entries into a map:
    Map<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<>(8); // initial capacity = 8
    for (String[] arr : unsortedList) {
      map.put(arr[0], arr);
    }
/*
    // Alternatively, if you really like the streams API:
    Map<String,String[]> map
        = unsortedList.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0],
                                                s -> s,
                                                (a,b) -> a)); // in case there are two mappings
*/

    // fetch the transits from Copenhagen to Chicago for printing:
    String begin = "Copenhagen";
    String end   = "Chicago";
    String next  = begin;

    System.out.println("Just transits:");
    System.out.print(begin);
    while (!next.equals(end)) {
       next = map.get(next)[1];
       System.out.print(" -> " + next);  
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();


    // fetch the transits from Copenhagen to Chicago back to a new list:
    next = begin;  // starting over
    List<String[]> sortedLimitedList = new ArrayList<>(8);

    while (!next.equals(end)) {
      String[] current = map.get(next); 
      next = current[1];
      sortedLimitedList.add(current);
    }

    System.out.println("List of Start, End:");    
    sortedLimitedList.stream()
                     .forEach(a -> System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a)));
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Results:

```
Just transits:
Copenhagen -> Amsterdam -> Rotterdam -> New York -> Chicago

List of Start, End:
[Copenhagen, Amsterdam][Amsterdam, Rotterdam][Rotterdam, New York][New York, Chicago]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think stream API won't help you in this case. my solution is like this:

I suppose you have and object to represent stations. *as @MartinBG created an object for start and end station*

so first you need to store all stations start and end points on the map.

```
List<Item> items = List.of(
            new Item("B", "C"),
            new Item("D", "E"),
            new Item("A", "B"),
            new Item("E", "F"),
            new Item("C", "D"));

Map<String,String> map = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getStart,Item::getEnd));
```

then you can use a mthod like this:

```
private static Map<String,String> route(Map<String,String> map, String start, String end){
    Map<String,String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    if (!map.containsKey(start))return null;
    String nextRoute = start;
    while (!map.get(nextRoute).equals(end))
      result.put(nextRoute,(nextRoute=map.get(nextRoute)));
    result.put(nextRoute,map.get(nextRoute));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this helps.

Comment: I see you condensed the map ;)

Comment: @Scratte, Yeah, Frankly I did not pay attention to your answer. When I completed the answer, I realized that we had used almost the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution, based on the assumptions that there will be only one `object` with a given `start`, only one object with a given `end` and that there is a valid path between those:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class FilterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> items = List.of(
                new Item("B", "C"),
                new Item("D", "E"),
                new Item("A", "B"),
                new Item("E", "F"),
                new Item("C", "D"));

        String from = "B";
        String to = "E";
        items.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getStart))
                .dropWhile(item -> !item.getStart().equals(from))
                .takeWhile(item -> !item.getStart().equals(to))
                .forEach(item -> System.out.printf("{%s, %s} ", item.getStart(), item.getEnd()));
    }

    private static class Item {
        private final String start;
        private final String end;

        private Item(String start, String end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public String getStart() {
            return this.start;
        }

        public String getEnd() {
            return this.end;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{B, C} {C, D} {D, E}
```

Comment: I think the items in the list is meant be something like ...{"Copenhagen", "Amsterdam"}{"Amsterdam","Rotterdam"}{"Rotterdam","New York"}{"New York","Chicago"}...

Comment: @Scratte Yes, therefor you can't really sort them.

Comment: @MartinBG the idea is nice, but this seems to work with only 3 nodes right? If I have n nodes it wouldn't.

Comment: @ErikB. Proposed solution works for any number of nodes